# Regex to only accept Numeric and Decimal Value not any special or character in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, uwp

How do I restrict special characters and character in a Textbox?
I'm using this code but I am not restricting special characters and character

code :-

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)sender).Text, @"^\\d*\\.?\\d*$"))
{
    // Write Code 

}
```

Comment: You may want to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524692/4466640). However this does probably the other of what you need. Make the `TextBox` accept letters and numbers. Just to give some idea.

Answer (score 5):

if you're using @ in front of string, you don't have to escape characters. So, remove all those extra backslash chars and your regex should work. Like this:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)sender).Text, @"^\d*\.?\d*$"))
```

EDIT:
use sites like [this](https://regex101.com) to test [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/3a45mY/1).

Comment: ThanK You Nino . It is working but when i remove Mark (!) . Thanks .