# Blocking Underscore Input in TextBox

Tags: c#

Blocking Underscore Input in TextBox

Hello All,

I'm trying to *block underscore* (`_`) from being entered into a `TextBox` but I'm having no luck:

```
private void CoupontextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsSymbol('_'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does that code do, that you do not want or expect?

Comment: @fildor, I'm trying to prevent the user from being able to enter an underscore into a textbox. Would the code above work? Thanks.

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF or what are talking about?

Comment: If WinForms: You may use PreviewKey to exclude it from being considered as an input key: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Typo? It should be `if (e.KeyChar == '_') e.Handled = true;`

Comment: Your code _would_ probably work, too, if the condition actually made sense. You need to check what the EventArgs tell you has been pressed. As is, this only checks If '_' is a symbol. Which will be true or false, _always_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block or restrict special characters from textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524105/how-to-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-textbox) with just one 'special' character, the '_'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have just a *typo*:

```
// if '_' character is a symbol? - no; false will be returned
char.IsSymbol('_')
```

is always `false`. You should put something like this

```
private void CoupontextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // if character that corresponds key pressed is '_' we handle the message 
    if (e.KeyChar == '_')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```